# How to suppress change of indentation after auto-completion in vim-latex-suite?

Tags: vim-latex

Whenever there's situation such as this,

```
\begin{document}
  \section{Some section}      
    \subsection{Creating processes
```

and I close the brackets, it removes the indent of the line, like this:

```
\begin{document}
  \section{Some section}      
  \subsection{Creating processes}
```

Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Is there a support for that editor I do not know? Can you ask there, because that seems to be a pure editor question ...

Comment: I thought it would be a good place to ask that question, provided that there are a few similar questions with the vim-latex tag. However, I'm happy to ask that question in a more appropriate place, if it exists.

Comment: I *think* this is specific to the vim-latex plugin, so fair game for here in my opinion.  There is also https://vi.stackexchange.com where it should be on-topic.

Comment: @rodetroner IMHO you should not indent sections and subsections.

Comment: @JouleV Probably that's the best solution. Thank you.